# Exclude Pattern Regex Question

Tags: regex, perl

```
/<%(?:==|=|#)?[^>]*%>/;
```

This regex isn't exactly right for my needs. The `[^>]` part should be `no pattern of '%>'`

This are the available regex-features: 
http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdebase-runtime/kate/regular-expressions.html

(there is no `?` for greedy quantifiers)

Comment: I think the OP is trying to find an alternative to the unavailable greedy quantifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The doc you linked to says lookaheads are supported, so this should work:

```
/<%(?:==|=|#)?(?:(?!%>).)*%>/
```

`(?:(?!%>).)*` allows the dot to match one character at a time, *after* the lookahead ensures that the character isn't the beginning of a `%>` sequence.  That's effectively what the non-greedy dot-star would be doing in `.*?%>`, if non-greedy quantifiers were supported.

By the way, the `(?:==|=|#)?` isn't really doing anything for you.  If that part is supposed to be required, you should remove the `?`.  If not, you might as well remove the whole thing; it's just taking up space.

Comment: Arg, didn't see that `(?:==|=|#)?` was in vain.